# Setting the "scale" parameter in igraphR and NetworkX Kamada-Kawai layout

Tags: python, r, layout, networkx, igraph

I am using the Kamada-Kawai layout from the igraph package in R. However, I would like to use a scaling factor parameter, like the one available in Python NetworkX Kamada-Kawai implementation, parameter `scale`. Check it [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.kamada_kawai_layout.html).

Thus, in my Python function, to do that I would proceed as follows:

```
# scale factor
my_scale = 8.92
# k.k. layout
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(my_sparse_matrix, scale=my_scale)
```

However, I would like to use the Kamada-Kawai function from the igraph R package, not Python. Is it possible to do something similar with the R implementation?

I'm calling the R function as follows:

```
ngw=graph.data.frame(my_df)
# k.k. layout
xy <- layout_(ngw,with_kk(weights=my_df$weight,dim=2))
```

In the igraph R I've checked the parameters `minx, miny, maxy, maxx`, which they define the dimensions of the graph, but I don't know how to set them all in a comparable way to the Python `scale` single parameter value above.

Thanks in advance!

Peixe